# Drawing Floats and Controlling Decimal Place

Tags: java

If you run this program you will notice that the table that displays the celsius conversion looks funky. What I have been trying to do is have it stop at the tenth place. I really would I appreciate any feedback. Thanks in advance.

**Output:**

[image: Output]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Foo extends Frame
{
    public Foo()
    {
        setTitle(" Fahrenheit To Celsius Chart");
        setSize(400, 600);
        setVisible(true);

        addWindowListener(
            new WindowAdapter()
            {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Foo chart = new Foo();
    }

    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 14 ));
            g.drawString("Fahrenheit", 70, 110);
            g.drawString("Celsius", 200, 110);

            int[] tempF = new int[25];
            int y = 100, x = 130;
            int y1 = 215, x1 = 130;
            tempF[0] = 0;


            int counter = 0;
            while(counter < 26)
            {
                int index = 0;
                String Fahrenheit = String.valueOf(tempF[index]);
                double tempC = (tempF[index] - 32) * (5/9.0);
                String Celsius = String.valueOf(tempC);
                String formatedCelcius = String.format("%.1f", tempC);
                g.drawString(Fahrenheit, y, x);
                g.drawString(Celsius, y1, x1);
                x += 15;
                x1 += 15;
                tempF[index] += 10;
                index++;
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you comment out `String formatedCelcius = String.format("%.1f", Celsius);` ?

Comment: When I left it in, it for some reason blanked out everything. The program ran and compiled but it wouldn't display anything at all.

Comment: Please *show us* the output you're getting and the output you're expecting. We shouldn't have to run your code to see that.

Comment: I apologize about that. I'm new to this site, and I'm only six month old in coding years :( . Please click on the link that reads "Output" to see the results. The expected results is the Celsius table needs to stop at the tenth place. I know how to accomplish this with the println() but with Graphics I am stuck.

Comment: Try it again with: `String formatedCelcius = String.format("%.1f", tempC);` -- you can't pass a string to a `%f` format specfier, you need to pass a double.

Comment: Erwin, if I am not mistaken the line right about it declares tempC as a double or am I looking at this wrong?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt give it as answer as  that is the only possible way. DDKGM: because of `%f` a floating point parameter is expected that will be turned into a string with one decimal. You passed a string earlier, and an error was thrown.

Comment: @DDKGM You're not passing `tempC`. You're passing `Celsius` which is a String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your feedback. I found the solution. The Math class has a function round() that did the trick. I put this in and it fixed the issue:

```
double tempC = (tempF[index] - 32) * (5/9.0);
double c = Math.round(tempC);
```

After changing this I'm getting the proper output:

[Final Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFaYz.png)

Again, thank you all for your feedback.

Best regards,

DDKGM

Answer (score 1):

The code for rendering the temperatures should look like:

```
String Fahrenheit = String.valueOf(tempF[index]);
double tempC = (tempF[index] - 32) * (5/9.0);
String formattedCelcius = String.format("%.1f", tempC);
g.drawString(Fahrenheit, y, x);
g.drawString(formattedCelcius, y1, x1);
```

In your code, you did:

```
String.format("%.1f", Celsius);
```

Rather than:

```
String.format("%.1f", tempC);
```

(I hope the difference is clear)
The %f format specifier expects a Double argument (like `tempC`) but you were passing in a String (`Celsius`)

This caused a `java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String` (which you may not have seen as the exception was thrown into the Swing event thread) which aborted the rest of `paint` method.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Erwin. I see exactly what you're talking about. I corrected the issue, and now it compiles without the error but it's still producing the same output. It seems like something in the code is bypassing the format call. I'm not sure what though.

Comment: Did you also change this line: `g.drawString(formattedCelcius, y1, x1);`  ? You need to draw `formattedCelsius`, not `Celsius`